# textwidth of innerHTML in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the textwidth of innerhtml in Javascript.

Tried clientwidth,$(p.width()) but still unable to get it.Can anyone please help. PFB the sample code

```
<div class="watermark">
 <p>ABCDEFGH</p>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't do magic. It has rules.

Comment: See answers to [Calculate text width with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.watermark p').width();
```